# Backbone event listener triggering on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm currently attempting to trigger a Bootstrap popover only on the hovered element. Unfortunately it's triggering on all that are on the page. Below is the Backbone script (in CoffeeScript):

```
Site.Views.Stories ||= {}

class Site.Views.Stories.IndexView extends Backbone.View
  template: JST["backbone/templates/stories/index"]

  initialize: () ->
    @options.stories.bind('reset', @addAll)

  addAll: () =>
    @options.stories.each(@addOne)

  addOne: (story) =>
    view = new Site.Views.Stories.StoryView({model : story})
    @$("#columns").append(view.render().el)

  render: =>
    $(@el).html(@template(stories: @options.stories.toJSON() ));
    @addAll()
    return this

  events: =>
    "mouseover .rating" : this.showhover

  showhover: => 
    this.$('.rating').popover('show');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have multiple `.rating` elements inside your view's `el` so this:

```
this.$('.rating').popover('show');
```

hits them all. If you just want the `.rating` that is receiving the event then say so by grabbing the specific `.rating` from the event handler's event argument:

```
showhover: (ev) =>
  $(ev.currentTarget).popover('show')
```

---

A couple other things while I'm here:

1. Backbone no longer automatically sets `@options`, if you want `@options` then you have to do it by hand in `initialize`:

   ```
   initialize: (@options) -> ...
   ```
2. You don't need to use a function for your `events`, this would be fine:

   ```
   events:
     "mouseover .rating" : 'showhover'
   ```
3. You don't need to `=>` all your methods. I don't think you need to do it for any of them (assuming you use an `events` object instead of a function) except `@addAll` but you can get around that one by using `@listenTo` or supplying the third argument to [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on).